# Selecting Tabular menu on Bootstrap takes back to parent link

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

My project is setup in this local link:

> localhost:12345/index.html#/BookCollection

In this page there are 3 Tab components from Bootstrap. Recent, Past and UpComing

When I click on any of those Tabs I am taken back to:

> localhost:12345/index.html#/

Whereas it was supposed to be:

> localhost:12345/index.html#/BookCollection#Recent

The other two Tabs links are:

> localhost:12345/index.html#/BookCollection#Past
>
> localhost:12345/index.html#/BookCollection#UpComing

Please note that I am not allowed to change this Link Structure below:

> localhost:12345/index.html#/BookCollection

This is the Bootstrap component I am using:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Recent">Recent</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Past">Past</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#UpComing">UpComing</a></li>
 </ul>

<div class="tab-content">

 <div id="Recent" class="tab-pane fade in active">
   <h3>Recent Books</h3>
   <p>Some content.</p>
 </div>

 <div id="Past" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Past Books</h3>
  <p>Some content in Past Books.</p>
 </div>

 <div id="UpComing" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>UpComing books</h3>
  <p>Some content in UpComing books.</p>
 </div>

</div>
```

And I need the Tabs components from Bootstrap to work.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your code snippet works just fine. Perhaps you can explain a little bit more (and use a site like bootply since your localhost isn't reachable).

See your code snippet working here:
http://www.bootply.com/Ny6q4guDgk